# Constraints/AutoLayout in Interface Builder results in White Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I am developing an iOS application in Xcode using Swift and am having difficulties with the 'actual' results of designs when using constraints.

Currently my constraints are set so that an `UIImageView` has equal width
and height of the superview (As to fill the screen).
As seen in the screenshot below from my iPhone 5s, there is a white bar at the
bottom that is approx. 60 pixels in height that is not in the source image.

[image: Screenshot on iPhone 5s]

Further possibly relevant info:

- Uses a regular `UIViewController`
- Only other constraints are centering in the X and Y
- `UIViewController` is subclassed only to use a custom font
- Removing the coloured bar at the top does not remove the white line
- On the Storyboard, there is no white line for any iPhone size

I've tried everything I can think of and scoured stackoverflow, please help!

Comment: Please use imgur.com for image hosting on stackoverflow. I've moved this image for you.

Comment: Are you using a `UINavigationController` or other parent view controller? Or is your `UIViewController` the storyboard's initial view controller?

Comment: Just an idea. Make your main view (parent view of your ImageView) other color than white (ie blue). If you see the blue color then it will be either a location problem vertically, sizing vertically or improper contentmode of the image.

Comment: @rob This view controller is the initial view controller. There is No parent view controller for this view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're view controller is embedded in a navigation controller, it could be from the toolbar, which is not controlled by your UIViewController but rather the containing view controller. In this case you could do something like this:

In the parent view controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DestinationViewController
    destinationVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
}
```

In the child view controller

```
class destinationVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }
}
```

If it isn't the toolbar that's causing the issue, then there are some ways to debug this. When I run into an issue like this, I like using XCode's view debugger. When you run the app in the simulator, navigate to the view that's causing the issue. Then, within XCode, go to "Debug" > "View Debugging" > "Capture View Hierarchy". This will freeze the app and snapshot the view currently being shown in the simulator. You can use your mouse to hover over various elements and views to see what exactly they are and how they're connected to assist you in shedding some insight into where the problem is occurring within your views/code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, this is a load of help. I'll check this out.

Comment: I was able to discover the problem utilising the "View Debugging" feature. Thanks a heap for your help!